# Sampling results with conditions in hive sql

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql, hive-partitions

I have a table that doesn't have a primary key and is partitioned by date; columns like this:

```
1. user_id  
2. device
3. region
4. datetime
5. and other columns
```

It contains user generated events from a website game, they trigger every second. I want to return a batch with all the events (including duplicate rows) generated by the first 6 users (top of the table) in the current day that check the conditions:

for region = US

```
- one user from iOS
- one user from android
- one user from PC
```

for region = EU

```
- one user from iOS
- one user from android
- one user from PC
```

Can you provide a sample code from where I should start? A friend of mine suggested something about RANK() but I never used it.

Thank you !

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT user_id, 
    event_post_time, 
    device, 
    region, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT player_id) over (partition by player_id) as ct_pid, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT region) over (partition by region) as ct_region, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT device) over (partition by device) as ct_device 
    FROM events 
    WHERE event_post_time = current_date() 
    AND region IN ('EU','US') 
    AND device IN ('ios','android','pc')) e 
WHERE ct_pid <= 6 
AND ct_region <= 2 
AND ct_device <= 3 
ORDER BY player_id
```

Adding dummy data at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1dea)
and expected output:

```
user_id device region date_generated
```

```
  1  ios  EU  22-05-18
  1  ios  EU  22-05-18
  1  ios  EU  22-05-18
  4  ios  US  22-05-18
  4  ios  US  22-05-18
  2  android  EU  22-05-18
  2  android  US  22-05-18
  4  pc  EU  22-05-18
  4  pc  EU  22-05-18
  4  pc  EU  22-05-18
  5  pc  US  22-05-18
```

Comment: Do you need basic sample like, SELECT * FROM ?  If you have the basic figured out but just can't figure out the ranking, throw that code in the question.   It will be easier to help.

Comment: Yes, the sample should be SELECT *

Comment: @sniperd
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT user_id, event_post_time, device, region, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT player_id) over (partition by player_id) as ct_pid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT region) over (partition by region) as ct_region,
    COUNT(DISTINCT device) over (partition by device) as ct_device
    FROM events
    WHERE 
        event_post_time = current_date() AND region IN ('EU','US') AND 
        device IN ('ios','android','pc')) e 
WHERE ct_pid <= 6 AND
ct_region <= 2 AND
ct_device <= 3 
ORDER BY player_id<code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this is what you are looking for.

```
select * from (
select rank() over (partition by region,device order by cn desc) as
top_num,player_id, region,device,cn from 
(
select count(*) as cn , player_id,region,device from 
test_table group by player_id,region,device 
)l
)t 
where top_num = 1;
```

Let me know if this helps.

OP EDIT:
I managed to make it work for what I wanted using your provided query; here is the final one

```
WITH combo 
 AS (SELECT user_id, 
            region, 
            device 
     FROM   (SELECT Rank() 
                      OVER ( 
                        partition BY region, device 
                        ORDER BY cn DESC) AS top_num, 
                    user_id, 
                    region, 
                    device, 
                    cn 
             FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS cn, 
                            user_id, 
                            region, 
                            device 
                     FROM   samples 
                     GROUP  BY user_id, 
                               region, 
                               device)l)t 
     WHERE  top_num = 1) 
SELECT s.user_id, 
   s.region, 
   s.device 
FROM   samples s 
   JOIN combo 
     ON s.user_id = combo.user_id 
        AND s.region = combo.region 
        AND s.device = combo.device
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code and it close to what I am looking for.
Here is a link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b53e1b) that has some dummy data.
The following output is what I need:

  user_id device region date_generated

<!-- -->

1 ios EU 22-05-18
1 ios EU 22-05-18
1 ios EU 22-05-18
4 ios US 22-05-18
4 ios US 22-05-18
2 android EU 22-05-18
2 android US 22-05-18
4 pc EU 22-05-18
4 pc EU 22-05-18
4 pc EU 22-05-18
5 pc US 22-05-18

Comment: The logic is good, but I need also all other rows for a combination.
Check the original question as I attached the expected output.

Thank you for replying btw, I will try to adapt what you gave me so maybe I can make work.